# Synchronizations vs thread safe collections vs atomic wrapper classes vs locks

Tags: multithreading, concurrent-programming

I am new to concurrent programming. As I was going through the topics I got confused between Synchronizations, thread safe collections, atomic wrapper classes, locks.
Locks and Synchronization do same work by making a piece of code thread safe. Why do we need thread safe collections or atomic wrapper classes then? As locking will enable only a single thread to access the code and won't let collections or primitive types to be thread unsafe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very wide question that you're asking. Problem is, not all of these things have a single, strict definition. For example, thread-safe collections might use various forms of synchronization (like e.g. locks or atomic operations) to achieve thread-safety. However, not even the term "thread-safe" is well-defined!

However, there is one thing you got wrong surely: Synchronization is the goal, while locks, mutexes, atomics etc are means to achieve that. Synchronization just means that different threads access resources in a synchronized way. In other words, they coordinate access so that they don't badly interact with each other. BTW: I'm talking here about threads, but the different entities could also be processes or even different computers, but let's keep it simple at first.

Now, you ask about the use of "thread safe collections or atomic wrapper classes" and why they are required at all. The answer is pretty simple, these things provide different interfaces or services on a higher level. For example, when I have a FIFO connecting two threads, it doesn't matter how they synchronize access to the underlying queue. If the interface for the two threads is implemented properly, you get certain guarantees. Doing so manually with just locks is possible but complicated, so providing these as high-level building blocks in addition to the low-level primitives just makes software development easier and the results more reliable.

Lastly, one advise for further questions: As initially mentioned, not all terms have a universal meaning associated with them. Therefore, it would help if you provided additional info, like in particular the programming language you intend to use.

Comment: thanks @Ulrich.. language is java... the explanation is very nice and descriptive

Answer (score 2):

Because you need to be careful when using synchronization. If you abuse of it, you may have performance issues. Using thread-safe collections when possible is usually better for performance and you make sure that you haven't errors or deadlocks.